# Bootstrap 3 Animated Column Resizing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hoping to improve my code a bit here and taking anyone's feedback to help.

I have a button that when clicked will hide/show the sidebar.

**Problem: when I toggle the sidebar the content area occasionally jumps instead smoothly expanding/contracting. It's not 100% of the time so I'm having a hard time diagnosing the cause.**

Here's my jsFiddle where I'm toying around with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryhollingsworth/Vb74j/

What's going on:

```
$('#toggler').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-sm-9');             
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('col-sm-3 col-sm-0');
});
```

Simply swapping column widths out. I created a new column class of col-sm-0.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign `.col-sm-0` a `min-height: 1px` (like Bootstrap does for its columns), and remove the `height: 0px` style.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4aTnN/

```
.col-sm-0 {
    width: 0px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: This, in addition to, removing height:0px works nicely. Thanks. I've obviously have been staring at this for far too long :)